# SQL Script to remove commas and Dollar signs

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Script I developed to remove commas and dollar signs from tables.

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[D_Document_FieldsData]
SET fieldvalue = REPLACE (fieldvalue, '$', '')
WHERE fieldvalue LIKE '$%' and doctypefieldid=1
```

and

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[D_Document_FieldsData]
SET fieldvalue = REPLACE (fieldvalue, ',', '')
WHERE fieldvalue LIKE ',%' and doctypefieldid=1
```

However, I noticed that the doctypefieldid has multiple entries.  For example, the doctypefieldid could equal 123, 138, 144,  and about 190 more location lines based on the select query I just ran.   What would be the best way to cover all the doctypefieldid(s)?

Comment: Removing the `and doctypefieldid=1` condition from the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover all doctypefieldid(s) irrespective of the id. Remove that  doctypefieldid=1 from the where clause.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[D_Document_FieldsData]
SET fieldvalue = REPLACE (fieldvalue, ',', '')
WHERE fieldvalue LIKE ',%' 

 UPDATE [dbo].[D_Document_FieldsData]
SET fieldvalue = REPLACE (fieldvalue, '$', '')
WHERE fieldvalue LIKE '$%'
```